# Which is the oldest non-fantasy movie to design unique weapon for the character?

Tags: first-appearance, props

When we think of a fantasy movie, along with the hero, their weapon comes to our minds too.

- Captain America - [Shield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVOQn.jpg)
- Green Lantern - [Power ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfvbY.jpg)
- Bat Man - [Batarangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zPAf.jpg)
- Thor - [Mjolnir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSXD9.jpg)

We can add many such unique weapons.

But this is not only limited to fantasy movies. Special weapons* are being designed for non-fantasy movies too. [Baahubali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baahubali_(franchise)) fame [S.S. Rajamouli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._S._Rajamouli) takes special care in designing [special weapons](https://pycker.com/articles/special-weapons-of-rajamouli-which-reinvented-action-sequences) for his movies.

Some action movies in [Telugu film industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_cinema)(nicknamed as Tollywood) also use this type of weaponography.

My question:

- Which is the  oldest non-fantasy** movie to design unique weapons for the protagonist or the actors?

  ---

** <sub>By  non- fantasy, I meant non-super hero movie and a movie which doesn't involve any magic (unlike Harry potter and Twilight). I am looking for a movie which is set in a real world.</sub>

* <sub>Weapons which are unique and non- conventional in appearance or usage and are designed for that movie. A signature weapon would do. Not the weapons which look like regular shield, sword and machine gun.</sub>

Comment: Do hooks for hands count as weapons?

Comment: ..or hand-swords / chainsaws etc? Also, define **non-fantasy** and **special weapons**.

Comment: yeah, I think we're going to need a clearer definition of exactly what you're wanting

Comment: What do you mean by "fantasy"??? Anything that's not possible in reality is "fantasy"... so most of the shows out there that have any sort of weaponry are fantasy to some point... short of historical fictionalizations.

Comment: For instance, 1949 Samson and Delilah portrays Samson slaying an army with a signature weapon: the jawbone of a donkey.  Is that a 'design'?  eh.

Comment: @infixed If hooks for  hands are used in other movies, I am afraid not. If they have special importance, yes. Not hand swords. I am looking like something like jawbone of a donkey.

Comment: @Catija Movies which are set in real world not magical world. Movies which are set in real life. I have clarified in the body. Do you think I should some more details?

Comment: There's a slippery slope here. What is your definition of a superhero? For example, Batman has no supernatural powers / metahuman abilities, unless you count being filthy rich. Can you clarify your criteria for a film which is "set in a real world"?

Comment: @faintsignal Haha. Batman is not a super natural being but everyone agrees he is a super hero. You can exclude Batman like characters from the list. I don't go by dictionary definition here.  For ""set in a real world"", I mean a movie which is not set in a fantasy world like Hogwarts or a magical world. The movies which are set in a real life and in a non-fantasy movie.

Comment: So then, do war movies count?

Comment: Georges Méliès attacked the moon with a rocket in 1902, does that count?

Comment: @DarthLocke Why not? They will be counted. The weapons should be special or non-conventional. That's the criteria.

Comment: @Sinister I wasn't sure because of the "hero" part. I did have something in mind, but I forget what it was. If I remember and look it up and find it be a helpful answer, I'll make an answer.

Comment: I don't think any of your examples even count as having been invented for the movie in question. Lenticular shields are historically real, magic rings appear all over literature and myth, a batarang is maybe a boomerang (do they ever come back?) but really just a "spiky thrown weapon" (knife, ninja star, that thing from Krull - already done), and Mjolnir is a (ridiculously proportioned) warhammer or club.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner I didn't mean them to be an examples for weapons invented for a movie. I mentioned them because they come to mind when we talk about those heroes. I want an example for non-fantasy and normal movie where a weapon comes to mind when we talk about a movie.

Answer (score 3):

1960, Peeping Tom (British). A camera that contains a knife, wielded by a serial killing photographer. Great film.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your time. But as said in [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72723/which-is-the-oldest-non-fantasy-movie-to-design-unique-weapon-for-the-character#comment117867_72723) comment, there is an account of a weapon from a 1949 movie which makes that newer one.

Comment: @NogShine - yes, but that example is fantasy; you asked for non-fantasy.